# Load a dll library on Java

Tags: java, c, swig, libraries

I need to load a library written in C on java. I have only dlls and header files.
 Since I didn't understand how to translate pointers or other derivated types from JNI documentation I tried to use an automating tool for this, gluegen and SWIG, but I couldn't manage on how to use them.

I tried to create an interface file for SWIG but it only gives errors. Is there an example on how to load a dll to a java program using ANY tool that works and can generate translated C function and types from .h files ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JNI example of how to do CRC32 in Java:

`CRC32.java`:

```
public class CRC32 {
    // JNI function must be declared native
    public static native int crc32(int crc, final byte[] buf);
    /* 
    public static void main(String[] argv) {}
    */
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("crc32"); // Load your dll with System.loadLibrary
    }
}
```

Use `javah -jni <Classname>` to create a header file
`CRC32.h`:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class CRC32 */

#ifndef _Included_CRC32
#define _Included_CRC32
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     CRC32
 * Method:    crc32
 * Signature: (I[B)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CRC32_crc32
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jbyteArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

`CRC32.c`:
This file shows examples of JNI usage:

```
/* For a look at the actual CRC32 algorithm, look at zlib's crc32.c */

#include <jni.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
 typedef unsigned __int8 uint8_t;
 typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
#else
# include <stdint.h>
#endif

#include "CRC32.h"

uint32_t crc32(uint32_t crc, const void *const buf, size_t len);


uint32_t crc32(uint32_t crc, const void *const buf, size_t len) {
    (void)crc;
    (void)buf;
    (void)len;
    return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CRC32_crc32(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls,
         jint jcrc, jbyteArray jbuf)
{
 size_t len;
 uint32_t crc;
 jint scrc;
 const void *buf;
 jthrowable exc;
 len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jbuf);
 crc = *((uint32_t *)&jcrc);
 buf = (*env)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(env, jbuf, 0);
 crc = crc32(crc, buf, len);
 (*env)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(env, jbuf, buf, 0);
 *((uint32_t *)&scrc) = crc;
 return scrc;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't see where I omitted important details or made mistakes. Both the Java and C code look unchanged.

Comment: I enclosed the javah -jni with backticks, and that solved the unescaped left-angle-bracket problem more elegantly. And I tend to forget that SO needs a double newline for block code or list formatting to work properly.